# How to code a lookup table in the objective function in PyOMO

Tags: lookup, pyomo

I need to solve an optimization problem to maximize the volume out of a group customers, which a function of parameter x.

```
S = customers.keys()
model_max_volume = ConcreteModel()

model_max_volume.x = Var(S, domain=PositiveIntegers, initialize=500)

model_max_volume.volume = Objective(expr=sum(volume(model_max_volume.x[acctnum], acctnum) for acctnum in S), sense=maximize)
```

In function **volume**, parameter x will change depending on a lookup table.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
x_lower_bound |x_upper_bound    |delta_change_lower_bound |delta change_upper_bound |change factor for x
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
500           |1000             |0.0                      |0.3                      | 0.8
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
500           |1000             |0.3                      |0.8                      | 0.4           
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1000          |2000             |0.0                      |0.5                      | 1.5           
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

for example, if x is set to 500, and the value of another parameter follows between the lower bound and upper bound, the value in the column "change factor for x" needs to be returned.

The returned value will be used in the **volume** function, as shown in below.

```
def volume(x, acctnum):
    
    global dict_lookup, dict_delta
       
    delta_change = (x-dict_delta[acctnum]['a'])/dict_delta[acctnum]['a']

    returned_factor = f(x, delta_change)  ???????

    volume = f(x, returned_factor)
    
    return volume
```

My question is how to implement the lookup in PyOMO. Greatly appreciate anyone here can help  me out!

Thanks!

Comment: Are the x values in your lookup table a set of distinct values that or is there an entry along the whole range of (continuous/integer) feasible values of x? I ask, because it sounds like you would want to make x a binary variable with the values in the lookup table as another index set. Then you can multiply the binary value of x by the corresponding value in the lookup table.

Comment: Thank you very much, @cookesd. x is a positive integer between 500 and 25000. I have updated the lookup table, as I forget to show the range of x. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to keep this a linear (integer) program? If so, I think you'll require some additional variables and constrains (variable for delta_change for each account number, binary variables identifying which set of bounds x and delta_change fall within and big M constraints to set the binary variables) to give your solver linear functions to know which change factor to select.